# Printing byte wise a double value is reversing the actual value

Tags: c, double, unions

Please find my sample code which demonstrates my problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    char b[8];
} byte_wise_double_t;

typedef union {
    byte_wise_double_t bwd;
    double val;
} DOUBLE_T;

int main() {
    double tmp;
    int ii;
    DOUBLE_T my_val;

    printf("Enter a value:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &tmp);
    printf("The read number is: %e\n", tmp);
    my_val.val = tmp;
    printf("Printing the value bytewise:\n");
    for (ii=0; ii<8; ii++) {
        printf("%02x", (my_val.bwd.b[ii] & 0xff));
    }

    printf("\nReverse printing the value bytewise:\n");
    for (ii=7; ii>=0; ii--) {
        printf("%02x", (my_val.bwd.b[ii] & 0xff));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you enter a floating value I print out the double value bytewise, first in the expected right order and then in reverse order. But it turns out that the second print statement gives the correct hex representation of the input double. Here is a sample output:

```
Enter a value:
11.23456
The read number is: 1.123456e+001
Printing the value bytewise:
47e6913f18782640
Reverse printing the value bytewise:
402678183f91e647
```

Please explain why this is happening.

Comment: *But it turns out that the second print statement gives the correct hex representation of the input double* How did you conclude that?

Comment: Using hex to binary converter this is the result:<br/>
402678183f91e647 = 1.12345600000000001017497197608E1<br/>
47e6913f18782640 = 2.3997742945776857759010524823E38

Comment: Your computer stores the bytes of the double in the order that you are seeing in the first print. This is sometimes called *little-endian* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is a little-endian vs. big-endian misunderstanding.

For simplicity, take a look at a 16-bit integer.  Lets say 0xaa55 (decimal 43605).

By default, this number is stored with the lower byte in the low slot and the high byte in the high slot.

```
16-bit: 0xaa55

8-bit: byte[1] = 0xaa, byte[0] = 0x55;
```

Your first statement is printing hex from the right to the left, your second statement is printing hex from the left to the right (as you read it).  Looking at my small integer example, your first for loop would print '55' then 'aa', reversing the low and high bytes.  Your second loop prints the number from the high byte to the low byte, just as you read it.

Comment: As I understand Endianess, it has to do with which of the bits in a byte is treated as MSB by the system. This does not explain the order in which bytes are stored. My guess is that somehow struct is causing this behavior.

Comment: @Tadatmya: Your understanding is apparently incomplete. Endianess is not limited to the bits in a byte (and a byte is not necessarily 8 bits, btw.).

Comment: @Tadatmya - Olaf is correct, 'endianness' not only refers to the bit order being MSB, but also the byte order.  Going back to my example of 0xaa55, how do you know which byte is the MSB?  Endianness.

Comment: @olaf Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running this code on an Intel processor. This processor stores values in memory in *little-endian* order, where bytes are stored starting from the *least significant* byte. So, for example, the 32-bit integer `0xdeadbeef` is stored in memory as "EF BE AD DE". This extends to 64-bit integers and doubles, too, which explains the reversal you're seeing.

If you want to print the hex value of your `double` the way you expect, union it with a `uint64_t` instead:

```
typedef union {
    uint64_t intval;
    double dblval;
} DOUBLE_T;

...

DOUBLE_T my_val;
my_val.dblval = 1.2345;
printf("%016llx\n", my_val.intval);
```

(Note: this is not portable code: it assumes that you can alias a `double` with a `uint64_t` which isn't true on all systems. However, it should work for GCC, Clang, or MSVC on typical Intel processors).